# How do get webpack publicPath to not include the port

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

We have multiple index files that we server from webpack-dev-server:

```
index.html = http://eventapp.localhost
site.html = http://eventsite.localhost
forms.html = http://regsites.localhost
```

We have an nginx proxy in front of these to server both https and http. When the webpack client connects to `sockjs-node` it seems to add the port and goes directly to the `webpack-dev-server` instead of going through our nginx proxy.   This makes it so HMR doesn't work if you are going through SSL since we don't launch the server with https.

Is there a way to tell it not to append the port when doing the sockjs negotiation and just have it continue to use the nginx proxy?

This is how we configure the server:

```
 devServer: {
            host: '0.0.0.0',

            /// Enable gzip
            compress: true,
            contentBase: './dist',
            /* Theoretically, the public option is better but they only support a single host
             *
             * This is a security issue not using public.
             * */
            disableHostCheck: true,
            // Do not enable HMR on the server, it is enabled with --hot
            // hot: true,
            before: (app) => {
                /* Serve the dev settings that are normally injected via nginx */
                app.get('/settings.js', function (req, res) {
                    const fullPath = path.join(__dirname, settingsFile);
                    res.sendFile(fullPath);
                });
                app.use(historyFallback({verbose: false}));

            },
        },
```

and this is how we launch it:

```
webpack-dev-server --hot-only --hot --env.BUILD_VERSION=development
```

We are using this client from `react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient` but it seems to try to connect without the port and then the upgrade negotiation happens and it tries to connect with the port.

We can't use the `public` and `publicPath` config options since we have the multiple indexes.  We just need the discovery of where to connect to only use `window.location` and not add extra information like the port.